# Error using ng2 component from an ng1 control on a hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm following [this guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) for upgrading an ng1.x app to an ng2 app.
I was able to bootstrap the hybrid application but when I tried to write a new ng2 component and then use it from an ng1 control I get the following error:

```
zone.js:571 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=%24%24UpgradeModule…s%2F%40angular%2Fcore%2Fbundles%2Fcore.umd.js%3A4152%3A37)%20%5Bangular%5D
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=%24%24UpgradeModule…s%2F%40angular%2Fcore%2Fbundles%2Fcore.umd.js%3A4152%3A37)%20%5Bangular%5D
    at :3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:412 [angular]
    at :3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:40:222 [angular]
    at q (angular.js:321) [angular]
    at g (angular.js:4601) [angular]
    at cb (angular.js:4523) [angular]
    at c (angular.js:1758) [angular]
    at Bc (angular.js:1779) [angular]
    at eval (upgrade_module.ts:236) [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.ts:261) [angular]
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125) [<root> => angular]
    at NgZone.run (ng_zone.ts:132) [<root>]
    at UpgradeModule.bootstrap (upgrade_module.ts:236) [<root>]
    at :3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:412 [angular]
    at :3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:40:222 [angular]
    at q (angular.js:321) [angular]
    at g (angular.js:4601) [angular]
    at cb (angular.js:4523) [angular]
    at c (angular.js:1758) [angular]
    at Bc (angular.js:1779) [angular]
    at eval (upgrade_module.ts:236) [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.ts:261) [angular]
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125) [<root> => angular]
    at NgZone.run (ng_zone.ts:132) [<root>]
    at UpgradeModule.bootstrap (upgrade_module.ts:236) [<root>]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:712) [<root>]
    at :3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:763:17 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464) [<root>]
```

main.ts:

```
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {TestComp} from "./ng2/test-comp/test-comp.component";
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;

    upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['myApp']);

});
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        TestComp,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        TestComp,
        ]
})
```

test-comp.component.ts:

```
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'test-comp',
    template:`<div>abcdef</div>`
})
export class TestComp{

}

angular.module('myApp',[])
    .directive(
        'TestComp',
        downgradeComponent({component: TestComp}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
    );
```

Comment: are you trying to access angular1 component from angular2 component?

Comment: The opposite - from angular 1 component to angular 2 component.